# feature extraction from websites

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, orb

this is more of a theoretical question

whenever i search the web for feature extracting and feature matching, the only results i get are about image objects.. like finding a face or a patterened pillow etc..

but what im trying to achive is a good feature matching (or extraction) from websites.. meaning im focusing on important objects in websites, plus the matching will most likely be between panels, tables or images (images are least likely)

using the opencv ORB or SIFT doesnt give me very good results
here's the code i've been using:

```
def feature_matching2(fp1, fp2, num_of_matches):
image1 = cv2.imread(fp1, 0)
image2 = cv2.imread(fp2, 0)

orb = cv2.ORB()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(image1, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(image2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

image3 = cv2.drawMatches(image1, kp1, image2, kp2, matches[:num_of_matches])

plt.imshow(image3)
plt.show()
return sum([match.distance for match in matches[:num_of_matches]])
```

so again, basically what im looking for is this:
1. a way to extract important features/objects from a website's screenshot
2. a feature matching algorithm that would fit large images that include text

*** edit***
the idea is to take a screenshot of 2 websites and compare their features not using the html at all

thank you

Comment: so you evaluate images of websites, or website code, or what? if websites are static (font, background, size, etc. don't change) you could use simple template matching. What's the aim?

Comment: i've edited the post. im comparing between features of 2 different website's screenshots. the aim is to find as many similar objects between the 2

Comment: how do you define "similar object"? Can you find border cases that you would treat as being "still similar" and "not similar enough" with example images?

Comment: eventually i'll use machine learning to conclude what "grade" of similarity is good enough or not. but i do need a robust way to check for similar features in those 2 webs

Comment: the problem is, that different kinds of similarity are computed in completely different ways and therefore the methods you would need to find such similarity are can differ very much. Probably (if you can't give proper examples), you would need some kind of machine learning right in the beginning to find a solution. Maybe try "deep-learning" or sth, maybe it can find the features for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try **HOG**(Histogram of Oriented Gradients) feature extraction. This technique counts occurrences of gradient orientation in localized portions of an image. And simple **Euclidean distance** is good for feature Matching.

Comment: any chance you describe a little further? or explain how to get the euclidean distance of 2 hogs? a hog of a simple image is an array of almost 40m slots

Comment: The formula is **Euclidean distance =  sqrt(sum((Mi-Ni).^2))** ,  where **Mi** is the pixels of second image and **Ni** is the pixels of first image. The HOG returns features as the size of image. You can normalize both image features and apply in euclidean distance or can by pixel by pixel process (but, both must be in same size). If obtained value is minimum, then both the images are similar.